# Emscripten memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-management, emscripten

I have a javascript function compiled from `C` with Emscritpen which use some amount of memory (about 8mb), and I need to call it often. (One call per 20 sec).

But after every call the amount of used memory increases. And eventually it starts to fail with:

`Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 100663296, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.`

If I increase an amount of memory, it works longer, but still fails eventually. I don't understand why EMScripten tries to enlarge a HEAP size after each call.

Some code samples:

```
var render = Module.cwrap('render_djvu', 'number', ['string']);
```

call:

```
FS.createDataFile("/", "test.djvu", byteArray, true, true);
removeRunDependency();
var heapPointer = render('test.djvu');
FS.truncate('test.djvu', 0);
FS.unlink('test.djvu');
```

UP: The problem was a memory leak in C++ code, we didn't free an allocated by C code memory. Eventually we were running out of space for heap and it required an increase. The HEAP array is persistent and is not cleared after each invocation as I initially thought.

Comment: JavaScript is a Garbage Collected language -- i.e. memory is not free'd until needed -- are you sure you are measuring the right thing?

Comment: You want us to figure out why the Emscripten code uses memory, but you don't show us the generated code or even tell us which function it is? I think we'd have to either see the actual code causing the problem or we'd have to have a runnable version that could be profiled.

Comment: This is a very big library but i think that i understand why it happens so i will mark for deleting this question soon.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand my problem so i reopened question and edit it a little. Attached code. https://github.com/saint3k/reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I didn't understand that if you are allocating memory in C/C++ program which will be compiled in JS. I though that on every call EMScripten will generate the new clear environment, which is not the case and the environment will be reused. So we still care about memory leaks.

Comment: Mind sharing what your solution looks like? I'm running into the same issue with a different library.